# How can I add a plaintext body to a RestSharp POST request?

Tags: httprequest, restsharp, plaintext

I am currently supporting an integration where messages sent to an external API need to be sent as plaintext on the request body and can be rather hefty at times. This excludes the method of using AddParameter with a RequestBody ParameterType as it only allows content up to 64 KB in size. Adding it using the AddFile method seems to add a whole bunch of other garbage to the text that's undesired and using AddBody requires that Restsharp serialize it to Json or XML which is not desired.

Is there a way to add a plaintext body to restsharp aside from these methods and that does not have a low size limitation?